# Best way to perform heavy data listing [Currently using RecyclerView]

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm not here to ask about how to accomplish 'X' task, but I want to do it better way than I'm doing it right now.

I will mention all the libraries used in this tasks, so any better recommendations are welcome.

Below is my project flow:

- Database is stored on remote host which is retrieved by its PHP API
  using *retrofit*.
- I download a epub file from remote host using
  *okHTTP*.
- Then use *epublib* to read the epub
- Extract it's resources to read it later [css / images etc.]
- Read each of it's page and store it in Array
- Pass the array to adapter and use *Webview* as a layout for outputting xHTML code
- Attach adapter to *RecyclerView*

Note : **The same epub can be read many times, so I don't extract every time. If it's a bit slower for first time, it's okay for me.**

The problem here is in this whole task. The output is *RecyclerView* with around *WebViews* in it, and 100-500 pages of data waiting to bind.
What's best way to perform these tasks / optimize recyclerview / binding data periodically or as per requirement?

**EDIT**

Another problem here I diagnosed, android RecyclerView only call *onBindViewHolder* as per requirement but since I use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for my WebView [Why? Because I don't want user to scroll page then scroll list when page ends]

*onBindViewHolder* Saves lot of CPU by just binding layout when needed, but in my app it's binding around 150 layout on initialization. If I give fixed height to `WebView`, It becomes lot smoother.

Is there any way to set height to WebView Through Programming Method so it will bind maximum 8-10 layout on initialization but 150.

Comment: You have one web view for each row?

Comment: Yes, each page in epub is an individual HTML page, and even if I put put all pages in single webview and remove recyclerview. I guess It'd be too heavy for single webview to handle that much data in a single instance. Tell me if it's misunderstood by me.

Comment: Are you using webViews as recycler view's row item?

Comment: @DevrimTuncer Yes. To load HTML data.

Comment: Can you use a textView and Html.fromHtml method to display your html data? That would be much more efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I never used it but, please read EDIT it my question, problem is since layout height is wrap content it's calling bind method for first 150 data sets. If I give fix height it reduces to 3-4 which makes it no more slower.

Comment: @DevrimTuncer is right. But this wont work with CSS and Images in epubs

Comment: @AnkitPise I feel it would be a better idea to use one WebView and put this epub as in list inside it.

Comment: if giving fix height work fine you can try giving max or min height.

Comment: using a webView is a great cost to an activity. Using it as a row item -which means many webViews- is a suicide:) Use a single webView as you said at your comment or try to use a textView as a row item and Html.fromHtml method.

Comment: @DevrimTuncer Thanks brother for it.
I've posted my own solution over this, and it consumes only 2 WebViews with all local data, didn't affect performance now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here's what I did to fix this thing.
If anyone ever encounter with this kind of issue I wish it'd help them

**Mistakes / Things done wrong.**

First of all I gave wrap_content height to WebView which was representing as a single row which holds data in a recyclerview. Since I added HTML data in it which had CSS / Images I guess it took a while to load and layout height went as low as possible. Which made space for more rows available on display. That made 150 pages of html code, and new webview for each as phone assumed 150 rows fits screen so that many rows are kept ready to alter with new data. Which made it mess.

**Fix**

I gave fixed height to webview around 500dp, or you can give match_parent but I'd recommend to keep it low so couple row set can be ready for caching.

Bind data on function `onBindViewHolder` with

```
holder.ePubWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentUrl.get(position), htmlStuff.get(position), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

set new WebViewClient with following code in it.

```
holder.ePubWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.ePubWebView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        holder.ePubWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

With this I changed WebView height to WRAP_CONTENT once it **finished loading**.

Now it's smoother, and again doesn't matter how many rows are there for recyclerview, it was just logical mistake. :)
Thanks guys